# Accented letters with R package Repmis

Tags: r, r-markdown, citations

I'm using `repmis` to handle the citations in my report, however it does not compile when the reference includes an accented character - in this case when citing the `nlme` package.

Is there a fix to this?

I tried adding `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` to my .RProfile, but this didn't help. My work around is to copy the reference into another bib file and use the symbol from Window's character map. Although this works, it's not the fix I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Error message:

> pandoc-citeproc: Cannot decode byte '\xe9':
>   Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream Error
>   running filter pandoc-citeproc: Filter returned error status 1 Error:
>   pandoc document conversion failed with error 83 Execution halted

Sample .Rmd:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Paul Stevenson"
date: "21 January 2019"
output: html_document
bibliography:
  - packages.bib
---

```{r}
library(repmis)
LoadandCite(pkgs = c("nlme"),
            file = "packages.bib")

```

Reference [@R-nlme]
````

bib entry:

```
@Manual{R-nlme,
  title = {nlme: Linear and Nonlinear Mixed Effects Models},
  author = {José Pinheiro and Douglas Bates and {R-core}},
  year = {2018},
  note = {R package version 3.1-137},
  url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=nlme},
}
```

sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.2  htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.5.2     yaml_2.2.0     
 [5] Rcpp_1.0.0      rmarkdown_1.11  knitr_1.21      xfun_0.4       
 [9] digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.12
```

Comment: `\xe9` is not a UTF-8 character.  It looks like Latin1 for  "é". From the error message, Pandoc is expecting UTF-8.  So I'd suggest reading in your `.bib` file, making sure it looks okay in your editor, then saving it explicitly in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, the bib file had a question mark, which I could fix by copying in a UTF-8 character. The issue is that repmis tries to automate the process of citing packages from information in the DESCRIPTION, ideally there would be a fix to allow it to work/re-encode whatever it gets.

Comment: If you're on Windows, `repmis` likely writes in the Latin1 encoding.  The `iconv` program can change file encodings; I forget if it's included in the Rtools collection, but should be available somehow if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a smoother work around by opening the `.bib` and saving with `write.table(fileEncoding = "UTF-8")`. See the `recoder` function below:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Paul Stevenson"
date: "21 January 2019"
output: html_document
bibliography:
  - packages.bib
---

```{r}
recoder <- function(x) {
  dat <- read.delim(file = x, header = F, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "")
  write.table(dat, file = x, row.names = F, quote = F, col.names = F, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
}

library(repmis)
library(nlme)
LoadandCite(pkgs = c("nlme", "biometrics"), file = "packages.bib")
recoder("packages.bib")

```

Reference [@R-nlme]
````